# Are the number of available web-domains limited?

Tags: web, ipv4

If there is a finite number of IPv4-addresses does that mean that there is also a finite number of web-domains ?

Comment: A single IP address can have multiple DNS names associated with it and the IPv4 address space is not the determining factor, especially when more and more systems are using IPv6. A domain name is limited to 253 characters using the char set [a-z0-9-.]. This will give you an upper limit on the number. Hint - it's large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word **no**

The length of a DNS name is limited to 255 octets. There is [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290167/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-dns-name) which explains all that in reasonable detail.

So if you figure in the number of letters in the (English) alphabet along with numbers you end up with a near infinite number of DNS names. When you add in other languages you get even closer to Infinity... ;-)

Note that the number of IPv4 addresses has *nothing* to do with the "web domains." Also IPv4 has been superseded by IPv6 which has a lot more IP addresses available, by several orders of magnitude.

In other words web domains are just another way of saying DNS names and DNS names don't rely on IP addresses, they merely refer to them. The IP address can change and as long as the DNS record that points to a specific IP address reflects the change [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) will still work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Each element of a domain name separated by [.] is called a "label".
The maximum length of each label is 63 characters, and a full
domain name can have a maximum of 253 characters.
Alphanumeric characters and hyphens can be used in labels,
but a domain name must not commence or end with a hyphen.
Further, uppercase and lowercase letters are treated as equivalent.

So, maximum of 252 characters, with at most 4 labels,
so at least 3 dots.

This gives as limit 26^250, which is rounded to :
5.5378x10^353.

A nice limit.

Comment: It might be neat to evaluate the 5.5378x10^353 to a real number, or at least have given the ipv4 address space as 2x10^32 for comparison of magnitudes.